# Asio SSL stream thread safe

Tags: multithreading, ssl, thread-safety, boost-asio

I was checking documentation on Asio, SSL part to be precise and run into [`ssl::stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html)

And the Thread safe statement:
`Shared objects: Unsafe. The application must also ensure that all asynchronous operations are performed within the same implicit or explicit strand.`
Now I understand that OpenSSL BIO doesn't alow concurrent `SSL_Read` and `SSL_Write` operations, but nowhere I could find which functions specificaly to use with `strand`.

- Because using `strand.post(async_read)` / `strand.post(async_write)` shouldn't (in my knowledge) ensure that concurrent `SSL_Read` and `SSL_Write` won't happen, because even though these async functions won't execute at once, they just return right away and thus don't read any data.
- Also using `strand` on handler functions also doesn't seem like any good (to me), since when these handlers are called data is already read and copyed into user-defined buffer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok after more googling I've found what I was looking for.
Solution was in example HTTP Server 3, which uses strand on completition handlers.
Even though I still don't understand how it helps, it does prevent concurrent SSL operations and thus is not crashing my program.